# Circuit status details with stem

Tags: circuit, stem

With stem I can list the active circuits and some [details about them](https://stem.torproject.org/api/response.html#stem.response.events.CircuitEvent)

What I would like to understand is: how can I know if one of the circuits has been used (it's dirty) or not (it's clean)?

This information should be available somewhere otherwise how can tor close it when the MaxCircuitDirtiness is reached?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think [tor's control port](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/main/control-spec.txt) exposes this.

Answer (score 0):

Tor does not expose this *type* of information anywhere - and for a good reason! Yes, you should be able to see(=enumerate) the circuits and network members you see in consensus - it's OK, but the whole privacy is broken if any session-related information will be exposed outside Tor's secure strongbox. That's the privacy architecture of the client.